# Setup/Guidance/Troubleshooting DPM 2010 Bare Metal Backups

Tags: windows-server-2008, scdpm, bare-metal

Having difficulties setting up Bare Metal recovery in DPM 2010.

Does anyone know of a good guide/walkthrough to talk me through a basic setup?  I have tried most of the DPM knowledge base without much luck.

I can perform System State backups, but as soon as I enable bare metal the jobs start failing.  Error codes are not coming up anything on google at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things off the top of me head:

1. BMR only works with 2008 and 2008 R2 servers.
2. BMR requires the Windows Server Backup feature to be installed on the server you're
   trying to backup

Keep an eye on the DPM 2010 team blog, it has some good info on there including a walkthrough of [how to do a BMR in DPM 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dpm/archive/2010/05/12/performing-a-bare-metal-restore-with-dpm-2010.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, All servers are 2008 R2 and have Windows Server Backup feature installed already.  The only guides I seem to find are those on how to perform a recovery, not actually get BMR working in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

"If you are using System State, you should be thinking about 10 to 15 gigabyte that is necessary on the protected server.  However, for the BMR, you don't need any space on the protected server because the data is sent straight to the DPM server.

DPM itself will not calculate the size for BMR but assumes 30 GB should be enough.  However, this is not always enough, but is an average for the size of all critical volumes if you haven't installed or placed anything else on it.  Just the OS.  So the best thing you can do is calculate yourself (roughly) what the size is of your critical volumes and resize the allocated space to that.

Critical volumes = Boot Volume + System Volume + Volume hosting system state data

Just my 2 cents,

Cheers

Mike Resseler"

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dpmssandbmrbackup/thread/c46d8a7f-0baf-4529-a3e8-9dab11ef6545

I had the same issue and when I would run the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\DPM\binBmrBackup.cmd" in a command prompt I would get a not enough free space. So I bumped up the DPM store from 30GB to 200GB since my c: drive on that server had 177GB of data on it.